# JSF Populate selectOneMenu from database and handle the enabled/disabled also

Tags: database, jsf, selectonemenu

Hi I am wondering the best way to implement this requirement.  I have a database table with a varchar2 field to populate the selectOneMenu.  On the same table is a column of type CHAR(1) having a 'Y' or 'N' value, and I want to use this to also disable/enable the field.

I was going for something simple like the first option demo in BalusC answer here [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-hselectonemenu-with-entities-from-database)
and Here was a post I looked at having to do with disabling items in selectOneMenu - [<h:selectOneMenu> with temporary disabled SelectItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008085/hselectonemenu-with-temporary-disabled-selectitems)

But I do not quite know how can I combine the two things above here in an EASY way to manage both enable/disabled and populating the list?

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932034/how-to-conditionally-render-an-fselectitem-tag Basically just use `itemDisabled` attribute along with a bit of CSS to hide the item from UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that the best way is to create a custom object to back the values here. For example: http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2011/12/automatic-to-object-conversion-in-jsf.html